# Using React Hook Form with other component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I want to create dynamic form with react-hook-form.

[image]

Below is my code.

I want to create a dialog for entering a detailed profile in a separate component and use it in MainForm.
I can display the DetailForm, but the values entered in it are not reflected.
Data on the DetailForm component is not included when submitting.

Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

##### MainForm

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  useForm,
  Controller,
  useFieldArray
} from 'react-hook-form';
import {
  Button,
  TextField,
  List,
  ListItem,
  IconButton,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import DetailForm from '@components/DetailForm'
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutline';


function MainForm(props:any) {
  const { control, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm({
    mode: 'onBlur',
    defaultValues: {
      profiles: [
        {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          phone: ''
        }
      ]
    }
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'profiles',
  });
  const onSubmit = () => {
    const data = getValues();
    console.log('data: ', data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <List>
        fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <ListItem>
              <Controller
                name={`profiles.${index}.firstName`}
                control={control}
                render={({field}) => 
                  <TextField
                    { ...field }
                    label="First Name"
                  />
                }
              />
              <Controller
                name={`profiles.${index}.lastName`}
                control={control}
                render={({field}) => 
                  <TextField
                    { ...field }
                    label="Last Name"
                  />
                }
              />
              <DetailForm index={index} />
            </ListItem>
          )
        })
      </List>
      <IconButton onClick={() => append({})}>
        <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Button
        type='submit'
      >
        SAVE
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

##### DetailForm

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  TextField,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function DetailForm(props: any) {
  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setDialogState(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogState(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={handleOpen}
      >
        Set Detail Profile
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={dialogState}>
        <DialogTitle>Detail Profile</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <TextField
            name={`profiles.${props.index}.email`}
            label="Email Address"
          />
          <TextField
            name={`profiles.${props.index}.phone`}
            label="Phone Number"
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register those fields inside your `<Dialog />` component - just pass `control` to it. It's also important to set an inline `defaultValue` when using `<Controller />` and `useFieldArray`. From the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller):

> inline `defaultValue` is required when working with `useFieldArray` by integrating with the value from fields object.

One other minor thing: You should also pass the complete `fieldId` to your `<Dialog />` component instead of just passing the `index`. This way it would be easier to change the `fieldId` in one place instead of editing all fields in your `<Dialog />` component.

**MainForm**

```
<ListItem key={item.id}>
  <Controller
    name={`profiles.${index}.firstName`}
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field }) => (
      <TextField {...field} label="First Name" />
    )}
  />
  <Controller
    name={`profiles.${index}.lastName`}
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field }) => (
      <TextField {...field} label="Last Name" />
    )}
  />
  <DetailForm control={control} fieldId={`profiles.${index}`} />
</ListItem>
```

**DetailForm**

```
export default function DetailForm({ control, fieldId }) {
  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setDialogState(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogState(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Set Detail Profile</Button>
      <Dialog open={dialogState}>
        <DialogTitle>Detail Profile</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <Controller
            name={`${fieldId}.email`}
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField {...field} label="Email Address" />
            )}
          />
          <Controller
            name={`${fieldId}.phone`}
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField {...field} label="Phone Number" />
            )}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Add</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]